# Hibernate Envers - request for changes in a List of the object

Tags: java, logging, hibernate-envers

I have a **Contractor** that has List of **Projects** he's involved with. The contract also has other lists such as Employees, payments and other fields (name, date etc).

My objective is to see which projects the contractor is associated to were changed.

example

```
Contractor C is involved in the following projects: 
1. Furman street <Active>
2. Park West <Active> 
3. Central Train Station <Active>
```

one day the user changes the project Park West from **Active** to **completed** etc.

So now each time I get the Contractor's revisions I get the entire information (projects, contacts, fields etc). Problem is that each time I touch the projects (list) - it goes to the db. My question, since I need to do a minimal touch to the db, how can I request projects revisions only? so I can tell what the user has done (example: add project X and mark completion for project Y)

What I have done so far is:

```
    AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);
    AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Contractor.class, false, true).add(AuditEntity.id().eq(objID));

    List<Contractor> contractors = query.getResultList();
```

and I also tried to ask for only projects like this (didn't work due to Null Pointer Exception )

```
...add(AuditEntity.property("projects").hasChanged());




public class Contractor implements Serializable 
{
     //fields... name, dates... 

     @DiffIgnore
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contractor")
     @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"contractor"}, allowSetters=true)
     @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
     private Set<ContractorProject> projects = new HashSet<>();  //this is a many to many relationship for a reason 

}
```

Comment: I assume you're interested solely in updates to those associated projects, correct?  Technically (from an Envers perspective), the act of adding or removing a project from a contractor is also a change, not just the act of modifying a project.

Comment: @Naros I'm interested in both ADD/MOD .thanks

Comment: Lets say a `Project` is assigned to a `Contractor`, modified a few times, and then it gets reassigned to another `Contractor`; perhaps in business speak the contractor had to give it up due to some conflict.  Should that `Project` be present at all under that `Contractor` from the perspective of what you're trying to render?

Comment: Correct, so say project R was assigned to Contractor C. The log show show that R is now 'INACTIVE' for C (but it shouldn't show that it was assigned to a diff contractor). Simply show the log from the C perspective. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments given that a `Project` cannot be *unassigned* from a `Contractor` once that link has been made and that you're solely interested in changes made to those said projects associated with a given `Contractor` instance, the best way to obtain the information in question would likely be through executing several audit queries to build that view.

The first thing you'll need is a list of `Project` ids that are associated to that `Contractor`.  You could acquire this information from the audit tables but I believe it would likely be better just to obtain those directly from the normal entity data instead.

```
SELECT p.id FROM Contractor c JOIN c.projects p WHERE c.id = :contractorId
```

The above query is basically a projection-based query which given a contractor identifier, you obtain all the project identifiers that are associated to the contractor through the projects association.

Should you wish to acquire this via the audit tables instead, the first thing we'd need to determine is the maximum revision number for the contractor so we fetch the right snapshot of data.

```
// you might want to check if this collection is empty
// it should not be assuming you aren't removing data from the audit tables
// but sometimes people archive data, so its best to be thorough
List<Number> revs = reader.getRevisions( Contractor.class, contractorId );

// The list of revisions are always in ascending order, so grab the last entry.
Number maxRevision = revs.get( revs.size() - 1 );

// Build the projection query
// This returns us the list of project ids, just like the HQL above
List projectIds = reader.createQuery()
   .forEntitiesAtRevision( Contractor.class, maxRevision )      
   .traverseRelation( "projects", JoinType.INNER )
   .addProjection( AuditEntity.property( "id" ).distinct() )
   .up()
   .add( AuditEntity.id().eq( contractorId ) )
   .getResultList();
```

Once you have this information, it comes down to executing an audit query in a loop for each `Project` to determine the information you need.

```
for ( Object projectId : projectIds ) {
  List results = reader.createQuery()
     .forRevisionsOfEntity( Project.class, false, false )
     .add( AuditEntity.id().eq( projectId ) )
     .addOrder( AuditEntity.revisionNumber().asc() );
  // At this point you have an list of object array values 
  // Index 0 - This is the instance of Project 
  // Index 1 - This is the revision entity, you can get the rev # and timestamp
  // Index 2 - Type of revision, see RevisionType
  //
  // So you can basically iterate the list in ascending order keeping track of
  // the prior Project and build a changeset for each project.
  //
  // This approach is often more efficient if you're needing to compare multiple
  // attributes on an entity rather than issuing a query to the database for 
  // each change made to a single property.
}
```

In the next major release of Envers, there will be some additional query methods that will allow you to get an object array that consists of the following

```
  // Index 0 - This is the instance of Project 
  // Index 1 - This is the revision entity, you can get the rev # and timestamp
  // Index 2 - Type of revision, see RevisionType
  // Index 3 - Array of properties changed at this revision
```

The key point here is index **3** where we will provide you with the properties that were modified, so you don't have to calculate those yourself.

Comment: first, big THANK YOU for all those pointers. I used the strategy you proposed with respect to the 'select' statement. It was more straight forward. In any event I need to loop one by one to get the objects with the revisions but I guess this is how it should be. Thanks again

Comment: Right.  The main reason here is that depending on your data model, a collection change can trigger a revision for the parent entity.  So if `Project` has a collection of something else which you modified at some point, the `Project` would have another row added; however none of the attributes on it would reflect having been changed; only the collection elements themselves were.  By fetching those revised `Project` objects, you can perform whatever _equality_ or _diff_ check you wish to determine whether that revision should be included in your report for that `Contractor`.